# Multiple pointers to point to the same block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macros, block

I am having a little issue here dealing with blocks and macros,  what i would like is to have 2 block pointers point to the same block that is being created.

Heres an example

```
Block a;  //Block is a typedef
Block b;
a=b=^{int craziness=0};
```

As of right now, a and b are 2 different blocks,  I want them to be the same block to make my macro easier

My macro would be `MACRO_NAME(method) Block method = self.block =^`

Self.block has a way of managing blocks in a list so i need the code to follow the way i have it since after the macro would follow my code,  so i would want the result to look like this

```
(void) somemethod
{
    MACRO_NAME(newBlock)
    {
        Int crazyness = 0;
    };
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Edit:  as a side note,  i know i can use MACRO_NAME(method,block) and get it to work, but it makes my code look ugly.

Comment: Your `block` property is presumably taking a copy of the Block when it's set. That would explain two different pointers. The executing code will still be identical. Overall, though, I really don't understand what you're trying to do, or why you're using a macro to do it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am trying to get all blocks i need to retain into an array,  and have anything i need to reference that block use a weak reference.  This way when I need to delete self, i delete the array, which kills all the block pointers and allows self to dealloc.  This is to avoid the weakself strongself steps needed inside a block to avoid circular retaining

Comment: "As of right now, a and b are 2 different blocks" No it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you do it like `self.block = MACRO_NAME(method)`?

And then,

```
MACRO_NAME(method) Block method = ^
```

Comment: I want self.block to be part of the macro,  its a behind the scenes type function

Answer (score 0):

Turns out. I had to add a third block pointer to get this to work correctly,  who knew, whatever it works,  thanks for the help